# what is this feature in Spyder called, and how can I do it in pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, spyder

in Spyder, I can write code in one window, and when I hit F5 to run it, my console becomes aware of everything that's happened.

If I define or import a class in my code (then run the code), I can then create instances of it in the terminal, for example

If I try to do this in pycharm (using shift+F10), the code runs, but I can't interact with the window afterwards.  If I call up a console (view> tool windows> python console), I can run code interactively, but it is not aware of the code I previously ran (using shift+F10)

is there any way around this?

Comment: It's a blend of iPython and spyder itself since it holds a global namespace between the console and your script. I don't know enough about pycharm to say whether you can faithfully replicate this; the only thing I have seen is people using `iPython.embed()`. Maybe that'd enough info to get you started on your search though.

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/scientific-tools.html